# Using JMeter plugins with justb4/jmeter Docker image results in error

Tags: docker, azure-devops, jmeter

**Goal**

I am using Docker to run JMeter in Azure Devops.  I am trying to use Blazemeter's Parallel Controller, which is not native to JMeter.  So, according to the justb4/jmeter image documentation, I used the following command to get the image going and run the JMeter test:

```
docker run --name jmetertest -i -v /home/vsts/work/1/s/plugins:/plugins -v $ROOTPATH:/test -w /test justb4/jmeter ${@:2}
```

**Error**

However, it produces the following error while trying to accommodate for the plugin (I know the plugin makes the difference due to testing without the plugin):

```
cp: can't create '/test/lib/ext': No such file or directory
```

As far as I understand, this is an error produced when one of the parent directories of the directory you are trying to make does not exist.  Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there actually something wrong with the image?

**References**

For reference, I will include links to the image documentation and the repository.

Image: https://hub.docker.com/r/justb4/jmeter

Repository: https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
```

Looking into [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L9)

```
if [ -d /plugins ]
then
    for plugin in /plugins/*.jar; do
        cp $plugin $(pwd)/lib/ext
    done;
fi
```

It basically copies the plugins from `/plugins` folder (if it is present) to `/lib/ext` folder **relative to current working directory**

I don't know why did you add this stanza `-w /test` to your command line but it explicitly "tells" the container that local working directory is `/test`, not `/opt/apache-jmeter-xxxx`, that's why the script is failing to copy the files.

---

In general I don't think that the approach is very valid because:

- In Azure DevOps you won't have your "local" folder (unless you want to add plugins binaries under the version control system)
- Some JMeter Plugins have other .jars as the [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) so when you're installing the plugin you should:

  - put the plugin itself under /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation
  - put the plugin dependencies under /lib folder of your JMeter installation

So I would recommend amending the Dockerfile, download [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)  and [installed the plugin(s) you need from the command line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)

Something like:

```
RUN wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar -P /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib/
RUN java -cp /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
RUN /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/bin/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install bzm-parallel
```